# Retrieving WSDL for a single operation

Tags: java, javascript, wsdl

Im a Newbie in wsdl parsing and my information about WSDL is very limited. 
I have a scenario in which there is a wsdl file with multiple operations and i want to get the wsdl for a specific operation from that. Is there any libs in java or JS to accomplish such a task . Or am i missing something.

Please correct me if there is anything wrong in the question ,

Thanks in Advance 
Bijesh

Comment: I'm not a java person but I've heard people use axis2 for services. Any reason why you need to parse the wsdl file manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDLs represent a single service with specific operations.  Those operations belong to the service can't be separated from the service itself.  In order to simply invoke one method you'll have to bind against the entire service (and all other operations and defined types).  If you are publishing the operation, you'll have to bind and publish all operations and types defined in the service.  There isn't really a way around that.

Now, in your case if you are using java and if you are acting as a client, you can do what Alfredo O alluded to and use a SOAP framework's tooling to generate all of the java client code for you.  From there it's just a matter of using the actual service class and invoking the method on that class that corresponds to the method you want to call.  You'll have to use the entire wsdl, but from the perspective of your code you won't have to worry about calling any other methods than the one that interests you.

Popular choices for generating a java client for a SOAP service are:

- [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)
- [Metro](http://metro.java.net/)
- [Apache Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Axis 2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) to auto-generate the java code needed to invoke those operations. Use the [wsdl2java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html) tool provided by Axis 2.